# React - Redux App : Handle Events in Stateless Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I asked same question with different form before but haven't reached proper solution yet. I want to avoid refreshing page when I delete data and define it with stateless component. There is my sample code:

**BookListElement.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BookList from '../components/bookList';
import { deleteBook } from '../store/actions/projectActions';

const BookListElement = ({books, deleteBook}) => {
  if(!books.length) {
    return (
      <div>
        No Books
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {Array.isArray(books) ? books.map(book => {
        return (
          <BookList book={book} deleteBook={deleteBook} key={book._id} />
        );
      }): <h1>something wrong.</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    books: state.books
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    deleteBook: _id => {
      dispatch(deleteBook(_id));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BookListElement);
```

**bookList.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
  borderBottom: '2px solid #eee',
  background: '#fafafa',
  margin: '.75rem auto',
  padding: '.6rem 1rem',
  maxWidth: '500px',
  borderRadius: '7px'
};

const BookList = ({ book: { author, publication, publisher, _id }, deleteBook }) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBook(_id);
  }
  return (
        <form>
      <div className="collection-item" style={styles} key={_id}>
        <h2>{author}</h2>
        <p>{publication}</p>
        <p>{publisher}</p>
        <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className="large material-icons">delete_forever</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

**action.js**

```
export const deleteBookSuccess = _id => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_BOOK,
    payload: {
      _id
    }
  }
};

export const deleteBook = _id => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.delete(`${apiUrl}/${_id}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(deleteBookSuccess(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};
```

**reducer.js**

```
const projectReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    case DELETE_BOOK:
          let afterDelete = state.filter(book => {
            return book._id !== action.payload._id
          });
          return afterDelete;
}
```

As you can see, I defined `handleClick` into `onClick` over `bookList.js` and page still needs to refresh after deleting data. How should I overcome that issue properly as a junior ?

Comment: In your condensed snippet of `projectReducer`, your `switch` statement is is switching on `action.type` right? Also, you are sure that `response.data` in action creator `deleteBook` is just the `_id` value? It's not nested inside an object property? It's not something like `{ _id: "123" }`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Its all set properly as you said.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify "its all set properly as you said."? If you log `afterDelete` in your reducer, can see you the difference in array length, as in the deleted item no longer being in the array?

Comment: Switching statement through action.type and I can see the difference in array when I delete data. Might be wrong define route parameter ?

Comment: See my updated answer, try wrapping connected BookListElement with `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`.

Comment: The refresh isn't happening because connected routed components need to use withRouter for componentShouldUpdate purposes

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you haven't set a type for `<button>`. For most browsers, if no type is specified it's set to `<button type='submit'>`.

Set it to `<button type='button'>` inside your BookList to avoid submitting the form.

Comment: Did it but still needs to refresh.

Comment: You mean the page is still refreshing or you need to refresh the page for the list to update?

Comment: When I trigger button to delete data, I've to refresh the page to see update with onClick={handleSubmit} define.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the native `<form>` submit event is still happening causing the page to refresh on button click. Try the following to prevent the native form by targeting the `onSubmit` event on the `<form>` element. This which would allow you to `preventDefault()` on the submit event.

```
// ...

const BookList = ({ book: { author, publication, publisher, _id }, deleteBook }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBook(_id);
  }
  return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="collection-item" style={styles} key={_id}>
        <h2>{author}</h2>
        <p>{publication}</p>
        <p>{publisher}</p>
        <button type="submit" className="btn waves-effect waves-light">
          <i className="large material-icons">delete_forever</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

Note: with the `onSubmit` on the `<form>` element, you need to remove `onClick` from the button. With `<button type="submit"`, clicking the button will cause a form submit event to occur which would be handled in `handleSubmit`.

**Update:**

Given you are using React Router, you need to make sure you are using [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) for [Redux Integration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration). Try wrappping your `BookListElement` with the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher order component. This is assuming you are using `react-router-dom`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import BookList from '../components/bookList';
import { deleteBook } from '../store/actions/projectActions';

// ...

export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BookListElement));
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: You need to provide more explanation of what you mean.

Comment: You need to share your actions and reducers. It means you may not be updating your state correctly on dispatch of the action.

Comment: Added action.js and reducer.js

Answer (score 0):

Your React code works as expected: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/so-52794886

If the Book List doesn't update after deleting one of the book, it might be that the `_id` returned from the server is of type string and _ids in the redux store are of type number, so filter predicate never matches and the item is never deleted from the list.

Comment: Thanks for contribution. I checked the type of _id over both side ( api and redux-store ) and each of them matches properly but I'll look into your sample to what I've missed or defined improper way.